# How could I transform a table extracted form the wed using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have extracted data from the web as a table. This is the format of the table I got:

| Locality | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Loc1 |  |
| 2001 | 102 |
| 2002 | 105 |
| Loc2 |  |
| 2001 | 206 |
| 2002 | 209 |
| Loc3 |  |
| 2001 | 412 |
| 2002 | 585 |

I need to reshape this table as:

| Locality | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Loc1 | 2001 | 102 |
| Loc1 | 2002 | 105 |
| Loc2 | 2001 | 206 |
| Loc2 | 2002 | 209 |
| Loc3 | 2001 | 412 |
| Loc3 | 2001 | 585 |

I am using pandas library in python.
Could anyone suggest me a script for that?

Thanks

Comment: Will your `loc1, loc2, etc` always have a null entries in your price column?

Comment: Hey @daidi06, welcome! Can you provide the code of the input table above?

Comment: Hi XXavier, Yes Price variable is always null for Loc1, Loc2, Loc3 ...

Comment: Thank you 7shoe. The first table is my DataFrame and right now I have it as a csv file. So when I read it in Pandas, this is the output. What I need is to transform it and get the second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some this like this? Separate the year based on the null values and forward fill the locality and finally dropna rows.

```
import numpy as np
df = df.assign(Year=np.where(df.Price.notnull(), df.Locality, np.nan))
df = df.assign(Locality=np.where(df.Year.notnull(), np.nan, df.Locality))
df['Locality'] = df['Locality'].fillna(method='ffill')
df.dropna(subset = ['Year'], axis=0)

Locality    Price   Year
1   Loc1    102.0   2001
2   Loc1    105.0   2002
4   Loc2    206.0   2001
5   Loc2    209.0   2002
7   Loc3    412.0   2001
8   Loc3    585.0   2002
```

Comment: Thank you so much XXavier. I've tried it and I got the expected result. Thanks again

Comment: @daidi06 do you mind accepting the answer if it helped?